# firefox websocket connected but messages don't get sent/received

Tags: php, firefox, websocket, localhost

I am playing with websockets, and got a little chat going based on php ratchet.

I am testing **locally**.

It works well in Chrome and IE, however in firefox it connects successfully but messages don't get sent/received.

I tested firefox on this website: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html and it seems to work fine when a message is sent, but like I said locally with me it is not working (does connect but no messages), so I guess I should do something somehow to make it work locally?

Comment: Are you sure it connects to the websocket? Firefox sent a funky `Connection` header, both with the HTTP `keep-alive` and the `Update` directives (with a capital U)... it's different from the other browsers and might get rejected. On some websocket implementations the update request might be recognized as an HTTP request (due to the `keep-alive` directive) or be ignored...

Comment: well it doesn't give any errors and on successful connection it should say "connected" and it does, so I guess it does connect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wireshark and filter websockets. 
You will see where the problem occured. But before you have to set your server on a private network and not in localhost. Wireshark doesn't work with localhost.